# "Finitely generated as an $R$-module"

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Please could somebody explain to me what it means for something to be finitely generated as an $R$-module? I can't seem to find a definition anywhere! Thanks!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_module.

Comment: @jemima Could you describe the process you used that failed to find the definition? I'm positive I could help you improve on it.

Comment: To me it is not obvious that "a finitely generated R-module" is the same thing as "finitely generated as an R-module".

Comment: @jemima: Could you give the two *different* definitions you are using? Although rest assured, they are definitely the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What follows does not literally answer the OP's question (this is done in the other answer), but may help clear up some confusion:

The OP states in comments that they are confused about the expression "finitely generated as an $R$-module".  This phrasing is used in contexts when an $R$-module $M$ might also be being considered with various subsidiary structures, e.g. perhaps also as an abelian group, or perhaps as an $S$-module, where $S$ is a subring or an overing of $R$.

In this context, an author might like to emphasize that $M$, when thought of as an $R$-module (rather than with any of its other structures that might be in play), is finitely generated. 
This is usually expressed via the phrase "$M$ is finitely generated *as an $R$-module*".

(E.g. if $S$ is a subring of $R$, this is weaker than saying that $M$ is f.g. as an $S$-module, while if $S$ is an overing of $R$, it is stronger than saying that $M$ is f.g. as an $S$-module.)

Mathematically, the meaning is identical to just writing that $M$ is a f.g. $R$-module.  Stylistically, it puts more emphasis on the fact that it is the $R$-module structure that is under consideration in the assertion, rather than some other structure.

Comment: A good point is being made here, for example finitely generated as a $R$ algebra is a totally different concept.

Answer (score 3):

It means that there is a finite set $\{m_1, \ldots m_k \} \subseteq M$ such that

$$M=\{r_1m_1+\cdots + r_km_k| r_1, \ldots  ,r_k \in R\}$$